# Java Intranet Applet not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, intranet

for days now I'm having a lot of issues of IE 11 with Java.

**History**

On my father's computer there's an Intranet Java app that works only with IE, not any other browser.
Until couple of days ago it worked almost perfect. I tried updating Java and since then it doesn't work with IE 11.

**No Solution**

I tried a lot Googling and looked for other peoples similar problems, none of the solutions people offered has worked for me.
I tried un-installing and re-installing many times. At first the Java was completely blocked, now I have installed an older version (Java 7) which works when I go to java.com and do the **Verify Java Version**.
However when I open the app (which opens through IE 11) I get this 404 message.
[image: 404 from Java Local Intranet Applet]

**Other Browsers**

In FireFox it actually opens the screen IE should open using Java, however the rest of the program is not compatible with FireFox so I am forced to use Java. But it shows that the problem is definitely in the hook of Java with IE but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Include links to any websites you are having problems with your questions. 404 server errors say what they mean....the file or directory was not found..... either you have incorrectly typed the web address or the web site has changed and removed folders or files. Your screen shot shows a conical address that looks like it could be for your dads router/modem.... Contact the manufacturer or your ISP for instructions and or information about changes to their products... (modem and routers can receive firmware updates)

Comment: Use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone your IE settings map the conical address to... expected Internet.

go Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default".. there IE security zone settings affecting Java JRT applets and objects and scripting which are granular, by zone.... scripted unsigned 32bit applets are not allowed to run on sites in the Internet zone.

Comment: It's already on the default... And I don't think it's in the router since in FireFox it works.

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, Intranet Sites>Advanced tab, add http://10.2.2.20/ to your Intranet sites list. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to confirm that it is indeed in the Intranet zone.